# UIImageView circular en UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, swift2

Estoy intentando poner un UIImageview Circular en un UITableViewCell y no estoy teniendo mucho exito :(.

En mi clase TableViewCell

```
class ComentariosTVCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var photoUser: UIImageView!

//weak var photoUser: UIImageView!

override func layoutSubviews() {


   
    photoUser.round()
    
    /*
     photoUser.layer.borderWidth = 1
     photoUser.layer.masksToBounds = true
     photoUser.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    
     photoUser.layer.cornerRadius = 40.0 //photoUser.bounds.height/2
    print("frame: ", photoUser.frame)
     photoUser.clipsToBounds = true*/
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}}


public extension UIView {
public func round() {
    let width = bounds.width < bounds.height ? bounds.width : bounds.height
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(bounds.midX - width / 2, bounds.midY - width / 2, width, width)).CGPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}}
```

y al cargar la tabla la vista no carga correctamente si no hasta que se selecciona alguna de las celdas o se hace scrool.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en donde estoy fallando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizás es que te estás complicando. Lo más simple y rápido que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //......

    photoUser.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(photoUser.bounds) / 2.0
    photoUser.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //......

}
```

Básicamente lo que estás haciendo aquí es redondear el `UIImageView` y asegurándote con el `maskToBounds` que la imagen no se salga del `UIImageView`. Probablemente ésta es la mejor forma y la que mejor rendimiento te dará.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1**

También puedes hacer la implementación en la subclase directamente

```
class ComentariosTVCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var photoUser: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            photoUser.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(photoUser.bounds) / 2.0
            photoUser.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

    //........

}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Habia intentado ese metodo y los UIImageView me salen en forma de diamante. Ahora entiendo que es por que el UIImageView debe mantener una relacion de aspecto de 1:1 con la misma dimension de largo y ancho. Estoy dibujando el UIImageView de 80x80 en un storyBoard. En teoria deberia funcionar pero cuando se ejecuta la app las dimensiones cambian supongo q por el autolayout. De que manera puedo dejar fija la dimension del UIImageview o hacer que si cambia de tamaño no pierda la relacion 1:1 para lograr la forma circular. Estoy perdido o voy por buen camino?

Comment: Correcto, para que la técnica que te he comentado funcione, debe de ser un `UIImageView` cuadrado. Para asegurarte que sea cuadrado, debes darle las constraints necesarias. Como mínimo deberás setear el `width` y el `height` para que queden fijos.